# display cells as improper fractions in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel one can format cells so that they display their numeric contents as fractions:

[image: Excel format cell screenshot]

But the fractions are reduced, i.e. `3/2` is written `1 1/2`. Is there a way to display improper fractions in Excel (I'm using 2013)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the custom formatting with this:

```
#/#
```

This will make the denominator be 1 digit in length. Though a potential problem is if you have, say 0.05 and use `#/#`. Excel will display it as `0/1`, so you usually want to use a longer denominator so you get `1/20`. To get a denominator of 2 digits or less in length:

```
#/##
```

And so on.

Comment: Tested in Excel 2016. It worked.